# Body Mass Index Stored Procedure Coding

Tags: plsql, user-input

PROBLEM

*Create the Body Mass Index Stored Procedure named bminfs_sp. Code it to accept three parameters (feet an integer, inches a double and weight a double). Nest two functions inside the SP. bodymassindex ( ) and weightcategory( ) define the inputs and output types to be consistent with the Java example. Provide source code listing, screen shots of the SP being executed with various inputs.*

I was absent the day of class that this was handed out and the Professor refuses to help me. Anyways, we were provided with this bit of coding:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE bminfs_sp
  IS
    out_record varchar2(80);
    return_val float;

      FUNCTION bodymassindex RETURN FLOAT IS
       numeric_val float;
       BEGIN
    numeric_val := 1.0;
    return numeric_val;
       END bodymassindex;
  -- Begin processing of bminfs_sp
  BEGIN
    --
    out_record := 'starting procedure';
    return_val := bodymassindex();
    dbms_output.put_line('returned value: ' || return_val);
  END;
  /
```

I've made a function for bodymassindex that would declare the feet, inches and weight variables and be able to return them.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE bminfs_sp
  IS
    out_record varchar2(80);
    return_val float;

      FUNCTION bodymassindex RETURN FLOAT IS
       numeric_val float;
       BEGIN
    numeric_val := 1.0;
    return numeric_val;
       END bodymassindex;
  -- Begin processing of bminfs_sp
  BEGIN
    --
    out_record := 'starting procedure';
    return_val := bodymassindex();
    dbms_output.put_line('returned value: ' || return_val);
  END;

  Function bodymassindex (feet IN INT,
 inches IN DOUBLE PRECISION,
 weight IN DOUBLE PRECISION)

 RETURN DOUBLE PRECISION IS 
  bmi_val DOUBLE precision;

   BEGIN
   END;
/
```

My questions is how do I "Nest two functions inside the SP.  bodymassindex ( ) and weightcategory( )  define the inputs and output types to be consistent with the Java example"? I defined the input types (I think), but not the output. I don't understand how to complete this assignment to these specifications?

Comment: So what exactly do you want?  You have not asked a question.  If you don't want do get a million downvotes, please read this - 
http://sscce.org/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Oops! I accidentally deleted my question when I added in the second bit of coding. thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Nobody is going to do your homework for you.  There are plenty of tutorials/examples on the web, such as -http://plsql-tutorial.com/plsql-procedures.htm .